# UICollectionView stuck in last cell while paging enable

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with paging enabled but somehow in last cell it is stuck if I tried to scroll right. I tried to disable bounce on scroll but still happening. It is not happening in xcode 10.3

[image]
[image]

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoPlayerCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoPlayerCollectionViewCell
       return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width , height: self.view.frame.height)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Your collectionView's constraints are zero to all sides, meaning it has the same frame as the view.frame?

Comment: Yes I added new screen shot @Starsky

Comment: I think it has something to do with the ```Content Insets```. Maybe change it from Automatic to Never. Go to your Storyboard, select your collectionView, go to ```Size Inspector``` tab, and find the ```Content Insets```. Also, what is selected for ```Inset From``` on the same tab?

Comment: I set it to never, it was automatic. But still happening. It should stop scrolling cause I enable paging. And also disable bounce. In first cell working great.